# How to create backups from user interface CRM?

Tags: laravel, backup, crm, database-backups

i am trying to make a backup option for my CRM. I have install this package https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v5/taking-backups/overview and i am using laravel 6^. I can backup my db and all system configuration with this package if i run backup:run from Terminal but this is not all i want. What i am looking for is to crate an interface where admin of page can make backup manually by clicking on options. For example like this: https://jobclass.laraclassifier.com/admin/backups (email: admin@demosite.com password: 123456) Does any one know how can i do something like this?

Comment: What have you got so far? Does something not work?

Comment: Basically, post to a route/controller method with the options the admin selected, then run the artisan command with those options

Comment: @brombeer No, have no problem. Everything works perfect, if i run `php artisan backup:run` on terminal i get backups file on `storage\app` . But i have try to add a route with `Artisan::call('backup:run')` but does not work in this way. So i can backup from terminal but i canot do same from view

Comment: What i want is to allow Admin to make backup from user interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Calling Commands Via Code**

Executing an Artisan command outside of the CLI. For example, you may wish to fire an Artisan command from a route or controller. You may use the call method on the Artisan facade to accomplish this. The on your controller you can do this:

```
public function createBackup(){
 Artisan::call('backup:run',['--only-db'=>true]);
 /// whatever you want to display

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This woks perfectly. Byt what if i want to backup all system? Not only db

Comment: Artisan::call('backup:run', ['--only-db']);

Comment: I mean if i want to backup system. `Artisan::call('backup:run', ['--only-db']);` This give me an error, The "1" argument does not exist.

Comment: @jokerr121 Isn't that what you already tried but didn't work? "_But i have try to add a route with Artisan::call('backup:run')..._" How does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add interface for `spatie/laravel-backup` package using another package which also uses this spatie package and provides beautiful user interface to interact with it, the package is : https://github.com/pavel-mironchik/laravel-backup-panel

Using composer you can ***install it*** by below command:

```
composer require pavel-mironchik/laravel-backup-panel
```

After installing, ***publish its resources*** using below Artisan command:

```
php artisan laravel-backup-panel:install
```

Then just goto `http://{your-project}/backup` and the interface will appear in your project you can customize it from `resources/views/vendor/laravel_backup_panel` directory.

The package provides UI for **creating backups** with options like **full backup, only db or only files backup** and also provides functions for **downloading** and **deleting the backup** and listing all the existing backups.

It will look like below screen:
[image]

I like it very much, isn't it just **elegant**?!!!